# R Shiny - Updating the value of a selectInput and progressBar simultaneously

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

The app below contains an `actionButton`, a `shinyWidgets::progressBar` and a `selectInput`:

[image]

When the `Start` button is clicked, an `observeEvent` is triggered in which I loop through the numbers 1-10 and increment the progress bar at each iteration. I would also like to update the value of the `selectInput` at each iteration but updateSelectInput does not work as expected. Instead of updating in tandem with the progress bar, the `selectInput` value is only updated once the loop has terminated. I don't understand why `updateProgressBar` works here but `updateSelectInput` doesn't?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Start"), #, onclick = "$('#my-modal').modal().focus();"
  shinyWidgets::progressBar(id = "pb", value = 0, display_pct = TRUE),
  selectInput('letters', 'choose', letters)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$go, {

    shinyWidgets::updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb", value = 0) # reinitialize to 0 if you run the calculation several times

    for (i in 1:10) {

      updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb", value = 100/10*i)

      updateSelectInput(session, 'letters', selected = letters[i])

      Sys.sleep(.5)

    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use ```withProgress``` and ```incProgress```  (see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html)) but it doesn't work either. But in fact I'm wondering: why would you want ```selectInput``` to update automatically if it stops at the letter "j"  (since it is the tenth letter)?

Comment: This behavior doesn't seem to work with any of the `updateFooInput` functions inside a for-loop (I tested radio buttons, text etc). As far as I can tell, the only internal difference is calling `session$sendInputMessage()` vs calling `session$sendCustomMessage()`.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this on the RStudio Community forum (https://community.rstudio.com/c/shiny), since this isn't about the progress bar, but the behavior of `sendInputMessage()` inside a for-loop, and there may be some good advice there.

Comment: @bretauv, thanks for looking into that. The app uses multiple progress indicators at different places on the page and I would have preferred to use `withProgress` but it doesn't allow me to change the position of a specific prog bar. I know how to change position using CSS but I would have to use a class rule `.shiny-notification {...}` that would apply to all progress indicators in my app. I used a `selectInput` just as a toy example. In the actual app, I am updating some text using `removeUI` and `insertUI` but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Brian. That's an interesting observation regarding sendInputMessage() vs sendCustomMessage(). My actual app udpates some text beneath the progressBar using `insertUI` and `removeUI`. These use `session$sendInsertUI` and `session$onFlushed` internally but the behaviour is the same as the `updateSelectInput`.

Comment: @Brian I've posted it here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-shiny-the-behaviour-of-sendinputmessage-vs-sendcustommessage-inside-a-for-loop/49834.

Answer (score 1):

It works if I set `immediate = T` in `removeUI` and `insertUI`. I got the idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908652/r-shiny-insertuis-immediate-argument-does-not-work-with-images) - it doesn't explain why `immediate = T` is needed though. According to the help page:

> Immediate - whether the UI object should be immediately inserted into the app when
>   you call insertUI, or whether Shiny should wait until all outputs have
>   been updated and all observers have been run (default).

But I don't understand what this means in the context of the for-loop. Does it have something to do with the scope of the for-loop?

If someone could post an explanation here I will accept their answer.

Updated code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Start"), #, onclick = "$('#my-modal').modal().focus();"
  shinyWidgets::progressBar(id = "pb", value = 0, display_pct = TRUE),
  div(id = 'placeholder')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$go, {

    shinyWidgets::updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb", value = 0) # reinitialize to 0 if you run the calculation several times

    for (i in 1:10) {

      updateProgressBar(session = session, id = "pb", value = 100/10*i)

      removeUI('#text', immediate = T)

      insertUI('#placeholder', ui = tags$p(id = 'text', paste('iteration:', i)), immediate = T)

      Sys.sleep(1)

    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```